# Converting Time strings into proper Formats in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string, datetime, time

I am tried to convert following strings into a proper Time in Ruby,

For.Ex.

```
 string_a = "1 minute, 6 seconds"   
 string_b = "3 minutes, 35 seconds"
```

I am trying to achieve is,

convert: `string_a` into time format: `1:06` - as it has just 6 second, adding  `0` in front of it.
  and     `string_b` into time format: `3.35`

Could you please someone help me out?

Comment: I tried using scan and then tried to handle separately for each string. But I am planning to make a kind of function so that I can pass string and as per that I will get converted string.  For ex. 
1 minute 0 second  = 1:0  2 minute 2 second = 2:02   and 3 minut 34 second = 3:34

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming input strings will always be in same format:

```
time = string_a.scan(/\d+/)
time[0] + ":" +  time[1].rjust(2,'0')
# => "1:06"

string_b = "3 minutes, 35 seconds"
timeb = string_b.scan(/\d+/)
timeb[0] + ":" +  timeb[1].rjust(2,'0')
# => "3:35"
```

You can make your regex stricter, however if the input strings are always in "*m minute, s seconds*" format then this should be sufficient.

Comment: in this case, `string_a ` works fine as it has single digit in seconds. But in `string_b` we have 2 digits in seconds. As per above code, for `string_`b I am getting :` "3:0" ` instead of  `3:35`.

Comment: @beginner_yaml_user you must be doing something wrong. Its working fine for me. I updated `string_b` example too in my answer. Please recheck.